# Improving/Modding a DIY guitar pedal?

Tags: pcb, audio

Ok, so I am constructing a DIY guitar pedal and I have a couple of modifications that I'm planning on adding (LED, Bass Cut/Treble Cut, etc.) But are there any mods I can make to this circuit to make it more overdriven?

Here's my circuit:[image]

Thanks for any help that you can offer!

Comment: i thought i was editing the title correctly changing "Modding" to "Modeling", but now i think the OP meant "Modifying".

Comment: Bypass 680 ohm with a capacitor 10uF

Comment: @Andyaka, that'll **really** crank it up.  and, yeah, i probably ignored biasing issues when i told the OP to reduce that resistor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so even with the gain cranked up (the collector resistance would be 53.3 K) it's still not driven hard enough?  i guess try lowering the 680 ohm resistor a little or lowering the 33K resistor).  either should make things louder and cause more clipping with the diodes.

Comment: How far can I go? Can I drop the 680 Ohm to maybe a 600 or even lower?

Comment: since i am not there and you are, all's i can say is try it and see if that cranks up the gain in that first stage sufficient to make it sufficiently "overdriven".